# in collaboration with or in cooperation with for the credits in a book

Tags: word-usage

Which words would you use *in cooperation with* or *in collaboration with* to describe someone who helped you in the production of the book.  For example, you the author explain orally what you want to express and the cooperator or collaborator writes it down himself in his own words. Which of the two phrases suits best?

Comment: In such a case, the "help" is acknowledged in the Preface to the book; this does not amount to collaboration or cooperation.  See also [writers.se]

Answer (score 2):

In a situation of ghostwriting, which seems to be what you are describing, you could simply use "Author Name with Writer's Name".

You *could* use "in collaboration with" but it's a bit lengthy and that is a consideration for publishers.